# Parsing JSON to a DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, drop-down-menu

I am trying to parse JSON results into a DropDownList in MVC, but so far my efforts have been fruitless.

I have the following code:

```
 public static SelectList getRoles(string sessionKey)
 {
    string URL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["JsonURL"].ToString();
    string appName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["appName"].ToString();
    string result = "";

    var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL + "rest/" + appName + "/Role?fields=id%2Cname");
    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/json";
    httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";

    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();         
    }
    var roles = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(result);
}
```

I've already created the classes for deserialization, but I have no idea on how to pass this data as a DropDownList to the MVC View.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you would normally do that:

The `DropDownListFor` HTML helper accepts both an `IEnumerable<T>` or a `SelectList` as the collection to be shown.

Let's assume your View's model is of type `TViewModel`. And `TViewModel` has a property that you want to fill with one of the dropdown list's options. Example: Your ViewModel is of type `Person` and it has the property `Gender` which you want to fill with one of the gender options.

You could have a View like this:

```
@model MvcApplication1.ViewModels.Contact

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Gender, Model.GenderOptions)
```

In the above example, `Model.Gender` is going to receive one of the `Model.GenderOptions` as the user selects one.

`Model.GenderOptions` should be either a `SelectList` or an `IEnumerable<T>`, in which T can be anything, or simply a `SelectListItem`.

You can find more information [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc).

Answer (score 0):

After further testing I found a proper answer. Model:

```
   var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        List<JToken> results = new List<JToken>();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            results = JObject.Parse(result).SelectToken("record").ToList();
        }
        List<Role> roles = new List<Role>();
        foreach(JObject token in results)
        {
            Role role = new Role();
            role.Id = Int32.Parse(token["id"].ToString());
            role.RoleName = token.SelectToken("name").ToString();
            roles.Add(role);
        }

        return roles;
```

View:

```
 @{List<Backend.Models.Role> roles = new Backend.Models.CreateUserModel().Load();}

@foreach (var role in roles)
                                {
                                    <option value="@role.Id">@role.RoleName</option>
                                }
```